# Equality of fields being deduced from isomorphism of Galois groups

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

I'm reading and attempting to understand a proof of the local Kronecker-Weber theorem in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606108 (page 17).

Let $K$ be a local field and $\sigma \in W(K^{LT}/K)$ with $\sigma|_{\hat{K}} = \operatorname{Frob}_K^{n}$ (i.e. $v(\sigma) = n > 0$). Let $L = K(\mu_n)$ and extend $\sigma$ to an element of $W(K^{\operatorname{ab}}/K)$. Let $E_\sigma \subset K^{\operatorname{ab}}$ be its fixed field. We have that $E_\sigma \cap K^{\operatorname{ur}} = L$ and $E_\sigma/L$ is totally ramified Galois. By definition $\operatorname{Gal}(K^{\operatorname{ab}}/E_\sigma) \cong \widehat{\Bbb Z}$ by $\sigma \mapsto 1$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K^{\operatorname{ur}}E_\sigma/E_\sigma) \cong \operatorname{Gal}(K^{\operatorname{ur}}/L) \cong \widehat{\Bbb Z}$, so the Galois groups of $K^{\operatorname{ab}}$ and $K^{\operatorname{ur}}E_\sigma$ over $E_\sigma$ are isomorphic. It is immediately concluded from this isomorphism that $K^{\operatorname{ab}} = K^{\operatorname{ur}}E_\sigma$.

> I don't understand how this isomorphism of Galois groups implies the equality $K^{\operatorname{ab}} = K^{\operatorname{ur}}E_\sigma$.

This would of course not usually be the case (e.g. $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)/\Bbb Q)$ and the Galois group of literally any other quadratic field).

Hopefully some number theorist could clarify this for me!

Comment: I think it goes like this: one of them contains the other, and when you compose one isomorphism and its inverse in the right order, the map is the natural restriction. Or you could (again using that there is a containment one way) argue that $\hat \mathbb Z$ does not have itself as a proper quotient. It does seem to be a tiny gap.

Comment: @TokenToucan Thanks! Do you have a reference/reason why $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ is not isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself?

Comment: @TokenToucan scratch that, $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ is residually finite (because profinite) and topologically finitely generated (procyclic) so it's Hopfian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two proofs (Following TokenToucan's comment):

**Conceptual proof:**
We have $E_\sigma \subset K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma \subset K^{\text{ab}}.$ By Galois theory we have

$$K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma = (K^{\text{ab}})^{\operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma)}$$
and

$$\operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma) = \ker\lbrace \operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/E_\sigma) \to \operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma/E_\sigma),\  \sigma \mapsto \sigma|_{K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma}\rbrace.$$

This map is bijective by assumption, so the kernel is trivial and $K^{\text{ab}} =K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma.$

**Cheat proof through $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$:** Both Galois groups are isomorphic to $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ and the SES
$$1 \to \operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma) \to \operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/E_\sigma) \to \operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma/E_\sigma) \to 1$$
implies that $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ is isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself, but $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ is residually finite (since it is profinite) and topologically finitely generated (it is a procyclic group) so it is Hopfian and hence not isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself. In particular, $\operatorname{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/K^{\text{ur}}E_\sigma) = 1$.

Comment: I had in mind a (maybe?) more elementary argument for why $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ is not a proper quotient of itself by a closed subgroup. The closed subgroups are in correspondence with the surnatural numbers. If any exponent is finite and nonzero, the quotient has torsion and hence isn't $\hat{\mathbb Z}$. If the exponent of some prime is $0$, tensor with the associated $\mathbb Z_p$ and observe you get a field, which can't happen if the quotient is really $\hat\mathbb Z$. Thus all exponents are infinite i.e. the subgroup is trivial.